# Do I need to be consistent with how I push messages to users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've gone through a few tutorials now and I seem to have a variety of methods of displaying messages to the users.

For example, in the controller I have this action:

```
  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated! Welcome to foodiker!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

And sometimes in the controller I have this:

```
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        current_user.recipes << @recipe
        format.html { redirect_to myrecipes_url, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I've also read about things like the responders gem and using that respond_with rather respond_to.

Does it matter if I'm pushing these in different formats or is it all the same? Am I missing a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a `flash` or `notice` messages in `redirect_to` method, it will set those messages in corresponding keys of `flash`.

Basically, these are equivalent:

```
redirect_to myrecipes_url, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.'

# The same as if you did this:
flash[:notice] = 'Recipe was successfully created.'
redirect_to myrecipes_url
```

It is mentioned in [the examples section](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to-label-Examples-3A) of the method documentation.